# Panel does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, naudio

I need to load a **User Control** in my **panel1** inside **Form1.cs**, the problem is that the **UserControl (AudioPlaybackPanel)** contains an **ImportingConstructor** (*[ImportMany]IEnumerable<>*) and I can't figure out what two arguments I should have in the **Form1 AudioPlaybackPanel(????)**.

*The error I get is: 'NAudio.App.AudioPlaybackPanel' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments*

Here is the **Form1.cs**

```
namespace NAudio.App
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AudioPlaybackPanel myPanel = new AudioPlaybackPanel(????);
            panel1.Controls.Add(myPanel);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my User Control Panel (**AudioPlaybackPanel.cs**):

```
namespace NAudio.App
{
    [Export]
    public partial class AudioPlaybackPanel : UserControl
    {
        private IWavePlayer waveOut;
        private string fileName = null;
        private WaveStream fileWaveStream;
        private Action<float> setVolumeDelegate;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public AudioPlaybackPanel([ImportMany]IEnumerable<IOutputDevicePlugin> outputDevicePlugins)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadOutputDevicePlugins(outputDevicePlugins);
        }


        [ImportMany(typeof(IInputFileFormatPlugin))]
        public IEnumerable<IInputFileFormatPlugin> InputFileFormats { get; set; }

        private void LoadOutputDevicePlugins(IEnumerable<IOutputDevicePlugin> outputDevicePlugins)
        {
            comboBoxOutputDevice.DisplayMember = "Name";
            comboBoxOutputDevice.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBoxOutputDevice_SelectedIndexChanged);
            foreach (var outputDevicePlugin in outputDevicePlugins.OrderBy(p => p.Priority))
            {
                comboBoxOutputDevice.Items.Add(outputDevicePlugin);
            }            
            comboBoxOutputDevice.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }




        void comboBoxOutputDevice_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panelOutputDeviceSettings.Controls.Clear();
            Control settingsPanel;
            if (SelectedOutputDevicePlugin.IsAvailable)
            {
                settingsPanel = SelectedOutputDevicePlugin.CreateSettingsPanel();
            }
            else
            {
                settingsPanel = new Label() { Text = "This output device is unavailable on your system", Dock=DockStyle.Fill };
            }
            panelOutputDeviceSettings.Controls.Add(settingsPanel);
        }

        private IOutputDevicePlugin SelectedOutputDevicePlugin
        {
            get { return (IOutputDevicePlugin)comboBoxOutputDevice.SelectedItem; }
        }


// The rest of the code continues from here on...

    }

}
```

Here is the Interface:

```
namespace NAudio.App
{
    public interface IOutputDevicePlugin
    {
        IWavePlayer CreateDevice(int latency);
        UserControl CreateSettingsPanel();
        string Name { get; }
        bool IsAvailable { get; }
        int Priority { get; }
    }
}
```

And just in case, here is one of the plugins:

DirectSoundOutPlugin.cs

```
namespace NAudio.App
{
    [Export(typeof(IOutputDevicePlugin))]
    class DirectSoundOutPlugin : IOutputDevicePlugin
    {
        private DirectSoundOutSettingsPanel settingsPanel;
        private bool isAvailable;

        public DirectSoundOutPlugin()
        {
            this.isAvailable = DirectSoundOut.Devices.Count() > 0;
        }

        public IWavePlayer CreateDevice(int latency)
        {
            return new DirectSoundOut(settingsPanel.SelectedDevice, latency);
        }

        public UserControl CreateSettingsPanel()
        {
            this.settingsPanel = new DirectSoundOutSettingsPanel();
            return this.settingsPanel;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return "DirectSound"; }
        }

        public bool IsAvailable
        {
            get { return isAvailable; }
        }

        public int Priority
        {
            get { return 3; } 
        }
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: It is set in a IOutputDevicePlugin.cs file, it implements the different type of "Plugins"

Comment: I just added one of the plugins @GrantWinney

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realize you are more than likely trying to modify the NAudioDemo application to your taste: https://github.com/SjB/NAudio/tree/master/NAudioDemo  Am I correct ?

Comment: @AJ152 it would have been VERY helpful if you'd given us the details from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry, I normally try not to post too much code to not make it too long, but someone else "asked" and so I added it. But if you can still help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, this demo application makes use of MEF, and this is probably where the constructor parameters get injected from.

Answer (score 1):

The error doesn't say it expects two arguments... it just says it doesn't take 0.

The constructor expects a single parameter - an  `IEnumerable<IOutputDevicePlugin>`:

```
public AudioPlaybackPanel([ImportMany]IEnumerable<IOutputDevicePlugin> outputDevicePlugins)
{
    ...
}
```

You need to find something that implements the `IOutputDevicePlugin` interface and pass a collection of it, even if it's just an empty collection. *(Passing null to the constructor will allow it to compile but will throw a runtime exception when you hit the loop in LoadOutputDevicePlugins.)*

---

Considering the update to your question, something like this will get you up and running (although I doubt it means very much to pass an empty list):

```
var myPanel = new AudioPlaybackPanel(new List<DirectSoundOutPlugin>());
panel1.Controls.Add(myPanel);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth asking whether you actually need to copy AudioPlaybackPanel.cs from the NAudio demo in its entirety. The reason it has this constructor is that it tries to demonstrate how you can use each and every one of NAudio's IWavePlayer implementations. But in a normal real-world application you would just select the one that was most appropriate for your use. e.g.

```
this.waveOut = new WaveOut();
waveOut.Init(new AudioFileReader("my file.mp3");
waveOut.Play();
```

So there's no need to incorporate the plug-in architecture from that particular demo, if all you want is just to play audio files.